# Angular dynamic component property binding

Tags: angular, angular-dynamic-components

I have created a dynamic component in Angular 6 with componentFactoryResolver, and I need to update one of its properties every 3 seconds.

```
const componentFactory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(componentType);
const component: ComponentRef<any> = vcr.createComponent(componentFactory);

component.instance.property = this.newData;

    setInterval(() => {
      this.loadNewData().then((data) => {
        this.newData = data;
      });
    }, 3000);
```

The property is not getting updated.
I found out that **dynamically generated components do not support property binding**. So, how can I update the property with the new data? Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but I found your question interesting... :)

I made a Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3gvrrz

As I wasn't completely sure about your requirements I made the example using `@Input()` and using a `BehaviorSubject` in a shared service.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  @ViewChild(ContainerDirective, { static: true }) container: ContainerDirective;
  DATA = ['Angular', 'Material', 'Nativescript', 'Ionic'];
  index = 0;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private commonService: CommonService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const viewContainerRef = this.container.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(HelloComponent);
    const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    (<HelloComponent>componentRef.instance).name = 'Starting...';

    setInterval(() => {
      if (this.index > this.DATA.length - 1) {
        this.index = 0;
      }
      const nextName: string = this.DATA[this.index++];
      (<HelloComponent>componentRef.instance).name = nextName;
      this.commonService.setName(nextName)
    }, 3000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [ng-interconnect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-interconnect) for communication in these types of use cases.

1. Create a broadcaster in your parent component

   ```
    let broadcaster = interconnect.createBroadcaster('home-messgae');
   ```
2. Receive from the broadcaster from inside the dynamic component

   ```
    interconnect.receiveFrom('home-message', '', (data) => {
       console.log('do something with ' + data);
    );
   ```
3. Start emitting from the parent component

   ```
   broadcaster.emit('hello dynamic child');
   ```

Article: https://charlie-code.medium.com/simplify-your-angular-development-using-ng-interconnect-1b94c68e9141

Answer (score 0):

Using your code example. You create a component factory as follows

```
const componentFactory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(componentType);
```

and then using the view container reference you create your component reference like this:

```
this.componentRef = vcr.createComponent(componentFactory);
```

You should be able to use this component reference to update your current component. By doing something like this:
`(this.componentRef.instance).value = this.value` inside your setInterval function. In your code it would look like this:

```
setInterval(() => {
  this.loadNewData().then((data) => {
    (this.componentRef.instance).newData = data;
  });
}, 3000);
```

If you place an `@Input() newData: any;` in your component that must receive the new data then your component should receive the data. Hopefully that is helpful and fully answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

## https://github.com/BhadraAnirban/dynamic_component_to_HTMLElement/blob/main/README.md

### We will pass data to the component properties.

### It will also work if you are using [innerHTML] to render the html content coming from Server.

```
<div [innerHtml]="templateString"></div>
```

#### Create a Component (here I have created - SignatureControlComponent) and add it to the entryComponent of module.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-signature-control',
  templateUrl: './signature-control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signature-control.component.scss']
})
export class SignatureControlComponent implements OnInit {
role: string;
}
```

In the app.nmodule-

```
entryComponents: [SignatureControlComponent]
```

#### In the main component (I have used EditTemplateComponent) where you are going to create the component and add to the HTML element.

Inject ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewContainerRef, Renderer2 using the constructor.

```
constructor( 
  private elem: ElementRef, private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
  private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private renderer: Renderer2) { }
```

Use ngAfterViewChecked life cycle hook to get HTML element using class (I have used the classname 'Signature'). This will also work [innerHTML] to render the html content coming from Server.

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
    if(!this.isElementsRendered)
    {
      
      let elements = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.Signature');
      if(elements.length > 0)
      {
        this.isElementsRendered = true;
        elements.forEach(element => {
          this.CreateSignatureComponent(element);
        })
      }
    }   
  }
```

Finally create the instance of the component and append to the element.

```
CreateSignatureComponent(element: HTMLElement){    
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(SignatureControlComponent);    
    let componentInstance = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    const loaderComponentElement = componentInstance.location.nativeElement;
  // Assign value to the property
    componentInstance.instance.role = 'PMKJ!';

    this.renderer.appendChild(element, loaderComponentElement);
  }
```